# how to make a Grid of NSImages?

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

What is the easiest way to make a grid of 4 by 5 NSimages on an NSWindow?

I am trying to use an NSTableView with Image cells but I can't seem to have more than 1 per column

Comment: I had the same question recently and I found using `NSCollectionView` would be good for this, although at WWDC 2015, Apple changed the way this class is used in Xcode with Objective-C. There has not been any tutorials or examples released that I could find. Here is a rather elusive link to the only example I could find for the new usage: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaSlideCollection/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to drag an NSImageView onto your window and then use the "embed in matrix" menu item under the Editor menu in IB.  Then set the number of rows and columns for the matrix